SKD 51: cannot read property 'NativeModule' of undefined
i got this error when updating from SDK 49 to SDK 51.
This error occurs on Android.
thanks for help.
Tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling but it didn't solve the problem
image error

I have run into the same error with the same upgrade (from SDK 49 to SDK 51), and I've not been able to figure it out yet.

@Bill, i created new expo then copy code to new project and it works, I think you can try it

is there any stable fix ????

i had that king of error on my react native expo code.i do not know why but it started woking fine after i run:
npx expo start --tunnel

this helped to open global tunnel using ngrok and everithing woking fina now.

wow that works.

Ah, this didn't work for me, I still get the same problem.

@BarryMichaelDoyle, i think you should create a new project expo and then copy code from old project to new project, it work for me.

Switching to yarn ended up being the only thing that worked for me.

Switching to yarn what do you mean??

I run expo run:android which produces this error. Terminate it.
Then running expo start -c made it work.
